# Pre-training without seeing data

Tags: neural-networks, weights, pre-training

Is there a solid reference on pre-training methods in deep neural networks which never see the actual inputs? Any such known thing in literature?

I guess a more correct term is "initialization using gradient methods" instead of "pre-training".

I see it like this: generating layerwise iid weights is the simplest approach. We can do better by unsupervised pre-training, if we have a dataset.
But what can be done between these two extremes?

Comment: is pretraining using another dataset allowed?

Comment: Sorry, no. I am interested in weight initialization approaches which operate with as little as possible  assumptions on the dataset. I suppose some inductive biases are unavoidable, but having e.g. MNIST in pre-training and Fashion-MNIST in training would be too much.

Comment: I see it like this: generating layerwise iid weights is the simplest approach. When seeing some dataset, we can do better by unsupervised pretraining. But what can be done between these two extremes?